# How can I cause a script to be run when a file is deleted?

Tags: bash, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, nautilus

I have an application which saves its data in the form of XML 'jobfiles' which contain lists of much larger .tif files that contain the actual raw data that the application generates. Typically, a user of the application would only care about the location of the XML jobfile: if this is moved or renamed, the list of .tif files would remain valid, since the full path to them (which will often be on a remote drive dedicated for the purpose) is recorded inside the file in a way that is transparent to the user. By doing things this way, the jobfile can be kept small rather than ballooning to tens of Gigabytes.

However, if the user decides to delete the jobfile from the OS (i.e. from a cmd window or Windows Explorer when in Windows, or from a bash shell or Nautilus when in Linux), there is a danger of chaos ensuing because of the link between the jobfile and its image data being severed. The image files associated with the jobfile will be 'orphaned', no longer accessible from the application but nevertheless still taking up space on the drive.

It would be easy enough to write a shell script that would parse the XML file, identify the image files which are listed within it, and delete them. Ensuring that this shell script is run *automatically* whenever the user deletes a file would solve my problem at a stroke. However, I have absolutely no idea how I might configure the OS so that it would run the script whenever a file is deleted, either in Windows or Linux.

Is there any way at all of doing this?

Comment: you can use watchers to implement an event and response approach, but you would have to write separate versions for both windows and linux, as they operate very differently. for windows I'd write a .net app, but this powershell script should do as well: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: On Linux, one would use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

Comment: Thank you; however, as far as I can see both the FileSystemWatcher class in .Net and the inotify API in Linux cause signals to be sent _after_ the file is deleted, by which time it will be too late to read the table of image files held within it (unless I can temporarily recover it from the recycle bin). What I'd been hoping to find is a way to get the script called after the user requests the deletion but _before_ the actual deletion takes place (a bit like a C++ destructor), so that the contents of the to-be-deleted file can still be read.

Comment: For that you will have to hook the windows API. I'm not actually certain its possible, but you want to interrupt the standard API behavior, so unless they give you a hook, that will be very difficult to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows port of [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) as mentioned in comments called [`inotify-win`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

**Download:**

https://github.com/thekid/inotify-win/archive/master.zip

**Compile:**

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe /out:inotifywait.exe src\*.cs
```

**Usage:**

```
$ inotifywait.exe
Usage: inotifywait [options] path [...]

Options:
-r/--recursive:  Recursively watch all files and subdirectories inside path
-m/--monitor:    Keep running until killed (e.g. via Ctrl+C)
-q/--quiet:      Do not output information about actions
-e/--event list: Events (create, modify, delete, move) to watch, 
                 comma-separated. Default: all
--format format: Format string for output.
--exclude:       Do not process any events whose filename matches the specified regex
--excludei:      Ditto, case-insensitive

Formats:
%e             : Event name
%f             : File name
%w             : Path name
%T             : Current date and time
```

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid a malicious action, the solution could be[`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx)in an NTFS file system

To protect a file from deletion:

```
icacls file.ext /deny Everyone:(DE)
rem To reset
icacls file.ext /reset
```

To protect a folder with it's content use:

```
icacls folder /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)(DE,DC)
rem To reset
icacls folder /reset
```

`*S-1-1-0` instead of`Everyone`for language independent, also `%USERNAME%` for the current user.

Comment: thank you, but please see my comment under the original question.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you could use a simple bash script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run code before and after prompting a user to delete a file

my_rm=/bin/rm
file1=$1

# Put the code you want to run pre-deletion here:
echo Running code before deleting ${file1}.

# Delete the file.
read -p "Are you sure you want to delete ${file1} (y/N): "  decision
if [ "$decision" == "Y" ] || [ "$decision" == "y" ]; then
        echo Deleting ${file1}...
        $my_rm $file1
        # Put the code you want to run post-deletion here:
        echo Running code after deleting ${file1}.
else
        echo No file deleted.
fi

# Put any cleanup code here:
echo Running cleanup code whether or not ${file1} was deleted.

exit
```

Assuming you call the script my-delete.sh, you would make it executable,

```
chmod +x my-delete.sh
```

and run it like so:

```
my-delete.sh jobfile.xml
```

Now, if you want to use `rm` to delete files, you can alias `rm` to the script:

```
alias rm='/path/to/my-delete.sh'
```

Add the previous line to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or wherever is appropriate for your system to make it permanent.

If you didn't want to run the extra code for files other than your jobfiles, you could add a test for file name or file type and only run the extra code for those files. The following script puts the special code into a function, then tests the filename to see if it contains the pattern 'jobfile'.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run code before and after prompting a user to delete a file

my_rm=/bin/rm
file1=$1
pattern='jobfile'

function rm_jobfile () {
        # Put the code you want to run pre-deletion here:
        echo Running code before deleting ${file1}.

        # Delete the file.
        read -p "Are you sure you want to delete ${file1} (y/N): "  decision
        if [ "$decision" == "Y" ] || [ "$decision" == "y" ]; then
                echo Deleting ${file1}...
                $my_rm $file1
                # Put the code you want to run post-deletion here:
                echo Running code after deleting ${file1}.
        else
                echo No file deleted.
        fi

        # Put any cleanup code here:
        echo Running cleanup code whether or not ${file1} was deleted.
}

# If the file is a jobfile, run the function, otherwise just delete it.
if [[ $file1 =~ $pattern ]]; then
          rm_jobfile $file1
else
        $my_rm $file1
fi

exit
```

Assuming you have created the alias described above, running

```
rm jobfile1.xml
```

will execute the function code in my-delete.sh but running

```
rm something.txt
```

will not.

Since Microsoft Windows now includes bash (and the Linux kernel, I believe), this should also run there, but I have not tested it. I'm sure a powershell script could be adapted from this also. I'm not a Windows guy. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's really neat; I can see how it would work in Linux, though I'd probably have to expand it to numerous extra cases, such as for example if the file were being deleted  as part of a whole directory tree being removed by rm -rf from a much higher level. Also, Windows doesn't have an alias mechanism of this sort when operating from a normal cmd window.  As you can imagine, since it's nearly four years since I asked this question I've developed a different workflow that avoids the need to do this.